# JavaScript calling a getter from its function

Tags: javascript, getter-setter

Trying to do something that in **pseudo code** would look like this:

```
(function(scope) {

    scope.doSomenthin = function() {

        if (x === y && this.onfinish) {
            //  If exists, run onfinish,  should return 'fin'
            this.onfinish();
        }
    }

})(scope);

window.scope = window.scope || (window.scope = {});
scope.doSomenthin().onfinish = function(){return 'fin'}
```

At run time if `onfinish` exists, run that function. Tried using getters/setter but at that point it will return undefined. Setting a timeout works but its not something I wish to do.

Any other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: *Pass* the function to the invocation (a *callback*) instead of assigning the function as a property on the return value. Alternatively, use promises.

Comment: That would work of course but I am trying to achieve that type of function, thanks.

Comment: No. Just don't do that. You cannot synchronously call a function that does not even exist at the time of execution.

Comment: That is the problem, the function does not exist when is called, was hoping to find something for that.

Comment: Yes - don't do it that way, instantiate the function beforehand and pass it instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I completely understand the question, but I think what you want comes down to setting the context for the functions you are calling. Is this what you are after?

```
//create a function that accesses an object's properties and methods with 'this'
var doSomethin = function() {
    var result = "nonfinish";

    if (this.onfinish) {
        //  If exists, run onfinish,  should return 'fin'
      result = this.onfinish();
    }

    return result;
}

//add an 'onfinish' method to the 'scope' object
scope = {
    onfinish: function(){return 'fin'}
}

//run the accessor function in the window context
alert(doSomethin());

//run the accessor function in scope's context
alert(doSomethin.call(scope));
```

Answer (score 0):

I see several mistakes with your code. This may be the results you are trying to achieve..

```
window.scope = window.scope || (window.scope = {});
scope.onfinish = function(){return 'fin'};

(function(scope) {

    scope.doSomenthin = function() {

        if (this.onfinish) {
            //  If exists, run onfinish,  should return 'fin'
            return this.onfinish();
        }
    }

})(scope);

alert(scope.doSomenthin());
```

---

- When you create the temporary scope here you give `scope` as a
  parameter. But `scope` is not defined yet.

  ```
  (function(scope) {

    scope.doSomenthin = function() {

      if (x === y && this.onfinish) {
          //  If exists, run onfinish,  should return 'fin'
          this.onfinish();
      }
    }

  })(scope);
  ```
- Your `scope.doSomenthin` function doesn't return any value. Because
  of that the value of `scope.doSomenthin()` is undifined. Therefore
  with `scope.doSomenthin().onfinish = function(){return 'fin'}` you
  are trying to set a property of undifined.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to approach is similar to event-driven programming. Don't just call the function right away, register it as an event handler instead. The following pseudo-code only shows my idea. It's not complete

```
//register the function here, instead of calling it immediately
event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
event.initEvent("myEvent", true, true);
document.addEventListener("myEvent", function(e) {
    e.scope.doSomenthin = function() {

        if (this.onfinish) {
            //  If exists, run onfinish,  should return 'fin'
            return this.onfinish();
        }
    }
});

......

//call the handler to handle the below event
window.scope = window.scope || (window.scope = {});
scope.doSomenthin().onfinish = function(){return 'fin'}
event.scope = scope;
document.body.dispatchEvent(event);
```

The above code is kind of silly. You have to design where to put and trigger the events.